# update-alternatives --config gcc doesn't change the compiler at all

Tags: gcc, ubuntu-18.04

I've installed gcc-6 on ubuntu 18 (default gcc-7) because cuda toolkits 9 requires this specific version of the compiler. I used this to have alternatives when to use gcc-6 or gcc-7

> sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-7 100
>
> --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-7
>
> sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-6 50
>
> --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-6

Then I can choose between the two of them as the default compiler

> sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
>
> There are 2 choices for the alternative gcc (providing /usr/bin/gcc).
>
> Selection    Path            Priority   Status
>
> ---
>
> *0            /usr/bin/gcc-7   100       auto mode
>
> 1            /usr/bin/gcc-6   50        manual mode
>
> 2            /usr/bin/gcc-7   100       manual mode
>
> Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 0

I 'm selecting [0], means gcc7. Then i check the version but still is gcc6

> gcc --version
>
> gcc (Ubuntu 6.5.0-2ubuntu1~18.04) 6.5.0 20181026

Any idea why it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. The thing when using cuda is that inside cuda folder you have a symbolic link to gcc. This link toke me everytime to gcc-6 instead of gcc-7. I changed the symbolic link, first removing it from cuda folder and then creating a new one which goes directly to gcc-7. In my case

> sudo rm /usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/gcc
>
> sudo rm /usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/g++
>
> sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-7 /usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/gcc
>
> sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++-7 /usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/g++

Now the compiler is gcc-7 and not gcc-6.

I was expecting a bad behavior of cuda with gcc-7 but everything is working good.